# Uninstalled programs cleaner

Tags: windows, software-rec, uninstall, cleaning

Generally, I'm looking for a recommendation for an uninstalled programs cleaner ?

What is it ? You have a program, you uninstall it, and it leaves a bunch of crap on your machine, starting from registry entries, to shortcuts that lead nowhere, up to a bunch of no more used files in Program Files and so ...

Registry cleaners usually do some of this stuff, but 'twas wondering, what are good tools that have it all in one package ?

I know such tools exist, 'cause in the past I've met with a few. Only I didn't need them then ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best by far IMHO is [Revo Uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html)

> Revo Uninstaller is a freeware
>   innovative uninstall utility much
>   faster than Windows Add/Remove applet.
>   With its advanced and fast algorithm,
>   Revo Uninstaller scans before and
>   after you uninstall an application.
>   After the program's regular
>   uninstaller runs, you can remove
>   additional unnecessary files, folders
>   and registry keys that are usually
>   left over on your computer. Even if
>   you have a broken installation, Revo
>   Uninstaller scans for an application's
>   data on your hard disk drives and in
>   the Windows registry and shows all
>   found files, folders and registry
>   items so you can delete them.

Comment: Uhmm, no. Revo unly uninstalls program which I have installed (like in add/rem. apps list). I'm looking for something that will for example go through Program Files, find files no longer belonging to any of the programs in add/rem. applications list, check the registry for setting in relation to those files, and then remove the lot.